# C++, Order map content based on second iter

Tags: c++, string, iterator, int

I have map as below

```
string word;
int occurance;
std::map< std::string, std::map<string, int> > map;
map[word]["count"] = occurance;
```

map output using iterator.

```
for(auto outer_iter=map.begin(); outer_iter!=map.end(); ++outer_iter) {
        for(auto inner_iter=outer_iter->second.begin(); inner_iter!=outer_iter->second.end(); ++inner_iter) {
            std::cout << outer_iter->first << '\t'  << inner_iter->second << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I want to display map by ordering the inner_iter->second value.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you are writing `std::cout`, then you should also write `std::map`!

Comment: oops sorry I have used using namespace std;

Comment: You might be interested in Boost.Bimap (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Yes, just do `myBimap.right` to obtain the reverse map, where elements are sorted by occurrence. See my answer for a link to an example.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach to use (unless profiling indicates otherwise) is to simply make an inside-out map when you need to print:

```
std::multimap<int, std::string> inverse_map;

for(auto outer_iter=map.begin(); outer_iter!=map.end(); ++outer_iter)
{
    for(auto inner_iter=outer_iter->second.begin(); inner_iter!=outer_iter->second.end(); ++inner_iter)
    {
        inverse_map.insert(std::make_pair(inner_iter->second, outer_iter->first));
    }
}
```

Then you just loop through the inverted map and print normally.

EDIT: I think you can get the double sorting you want by instead using a `set` of pairs:

```
std::set<std::pair<int, std::string> > inverse_map;

for(auto outer_iter=map.begin(); outer_iter!=map.end(); ++outer_iter)
{
    for(auto inner_iter=outer_iter->second.begin(); inner_iter!=outer_iter->second.end(); ++inner_iter)
    {
        inverse_map.insert(std::make_pair(inner_iter->second, outer_iter->first));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, but i have one problem which i forgot to mention, my bad. I need to display based on highest occurance to the lowest. Which I got it using your technique, but the second thing which i need to get is if occurance is same then it should display alphabetic order of word string

Comment: @user1579911: You can use a `reverse_iterator` on the `multimap`. Start from `rbegin()` and increment until `rend()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just had to remove "count" its so stupid of me. Anyway thanks I learnt how to reverse the map.

Comment: +1 for realizing the association isn't bijective (hence the multimap).

Comment: This solution is essentially doing a *tree sort* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort) ordered by occurence.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert into a `vector` and sort the contents accordingly.

**Edit:** Modified to sort from highest to lowest.

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> hist_item;
std::vector<hist_item> hist;
hist.reserve(map.size());

for(auto outer_iter=map.begin(); outer_iter!=map.end(); ++outer_iter) {
    for(auto inner_iter=outer_iter->second.begin();
        inner_iter!=outer_iter->second.end(); ++inner_iter) {
        hist.push_back(std::make_pair(outer_iter->first, inner_iter->second));
    }
}
std::sort(hist.begin(), hist.end(),
          [](const hist_item &a,const hist_item &b){return a.second>b.second;});
for (auto i = hist.begin(); i!= hist.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i->first << '\t' << i->second << std::endl;
}
```

This mimics your original output. I am not sure of the purpose of the inner map. If you are tracking properties other than `"count"` in it, your original output and this routine loses that association, and you just get multiple numbers associated with the outer word.

Comment: you are right i dont need "count" ahh i just want to bang my head onto a wall. Thanks a lot it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using Boost, you can use [Boost::Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html), which lets you associate words with counts, and counts with words (at the same time). This [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/example/repetitions_counter.cpp) shows how to compute the word count of a text and displays the histogram.

If you only need to display the sorted word count occasionally, it might be faster to use a regular `std::map` for building the word count map. Then you generate the sorted word count as needed using the techniques shown in the other answers. You'll probably have to run benchmarks to know which is faster.

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll add another solution that uses a [*heapsort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Using_a_priority_queue_to_sort) by pushing the maps pairs through a `std::priority_queue` to obtain the word count sorted by occurrence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> MyMap;

struct OrderByOccurence
{
    bool operator()(MyMap::const_reference lhs, MyMap::const_reference rhs)
    {
        // This will make the priority queue sort from highest word count
        // to lowest.
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;

        // This will make the priority queue sort from lowest word count
        // to highest.
        // return rhs.second < lhs.second;

        // Here, you can also check that if both counts are the same,
        // the elements should be ordered alphabetically by word.
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyMap m = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};

    std::priority_queue<std::pair<std::string, int>,
                        std::vector< std::pair<std::string, int> >,
                        OrderByOccurence> q;
    for (auto it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it)
        q.push(*it);

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        std::cout << q.top().first << " " << q.top().second << "\n";
        q.pop();
    }
}
```